# $\sum_{x\in X}|f(x)|=\sup\left\{\sum_{x\in F}|f(x)|:F \subset X\text{ is finite set} \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

The problem is :

For every function $f : X \rightarrow\ \mathbb C$, the equality
$\displaystyle \sum_{x\in X}|f(x)|=\sup\left\{\sum_{x\in F}|f(x)|:F \subset X\text{ is  finite set} \right\}$ holds.

I tried to solve this problem, using $(X,P(X)(\text{Power set of } X),c)$
$P(X)$ is a Power set of $X$
$c$ is counting measure : $c(A) = \text{the number of elements of }A$

Then, $\displaystyle \sum_{x\in X}|f(x)| =\int_X |f|dc$

So, the problem can be changed into

$\displaystyle \int_{x\in X} |f(x)|dc = \sup \left\{\int_{x\in F}|f(x)| : F \subset X\text{ is finite set}\right\}$

But, here's my question.
In $\mathbb R$, It was able to make $F \subset \mathbb R$ just like $[-N,N]$ or $E\cap[-N,N]$ to make some bounded set which can go to $\mathbb R$ when $N \rightarrow \infty$.

How to get a seq of finite set $F_n$ in arbitrary X? Is it okay to get any aribitrary of it? Please let me know the full solution of this problem.
Is there another way to solve this problem using $\sigma -$algebra which I wrote?

Comment: If $X$ is an arbitrary set (non necessarily countable) and $g$ a non-negative function on it,$$\sum_{x\in X}g(x)= \sup\left\{ \sum_{x\in F}g(x): F \subset X\text{ is finite}\right\}$$by definition (this sup may be $+\infty$).